# Android webview mulitple windows. How to detect is created window from html target="blank" or from javascript?

Tags: java, android, webview

Android webview mulitple windows. How to detect is created window from html target="blank" or it is a javascript popup?

I have next code in own browser:

```
 WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

also implementation create new windows in our ChromeClient:

```
            @Override
    public void onCreateWindow(WebView webView, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) { //logic for create new webview and set new url in it. }
```

We want to warn user about created new tab, but only if popup get from javascript code, because it is usually ad, and also many non ad pages use target="blank" attribute from html.

Comment: You want to execute some code when JS code creating alert? or something?

Comment: yep, our method  onCreateWindow called when JS try to open popup (alert with new url) when we enable settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

Comment: Did you tried use onJsBeforeUnload(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result)
Tell the client to display a dialog to confirm navigation away from the current page.

Comment: no, I didn't try the method. I'm trying now

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
    WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
    int type = result.getType();
    if (type == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE) {

    }
```

in if case we can handle action from html only, else different cases: auth2.0, or window.open("http://test.ua")

Answer (score 1):

Okay. First you can try do something by adding custom WebChromeClient. Methods

```
onJsBeforeUnload(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result)

onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result)
```

Also, ou can try by changing WebSettings of your WebView.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

I found this. `setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(boolean flag)`